# Trying to run function only if state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to run the set totals function only if the hour's state has changed. It is running every time the component mounts instead of only if the value changes. The this.state is apart of a context file that is extremely large so I only pasted the function being used

```
context.js (Class Component)
set Total
        if (this.state.hours > 0) {
               this.setState((prevState) => {
                 if (prevState.hours !== this.state.hours) {
                   console.log(prevState.hours);
                 }
                 return {
                   total: this.state.total + this.state.hours * ratePerHour * Math.PI,
                 };
               });
              console.log(this.state.total, '+', this.state.hours, '*', ratePerHour);
            }
    This is my component tha
     import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext,useRef } from 'react';
    import { ProductContext } from '../pages/oniContext';
    import { Container,Badge } from 'reactstrap';
    import {
      Subtitle,
      Description,
      Titlespan2,
    } from '../components/common/title/index';
    import { total } from '../components/total';
    export const FinalQuote = () => {
      const pCR = useContext(ProductContext);
        const prevCountRef = useRef();
    
    
        useEffect(() => {
          alert('Run')
          console.log(pCR.hours, 'Final Quote Run', pCR.total);
          pCR.setTotal();
          console.error(pCR.hours);
      }, [pCR.hours]);
    
      return (
        <section className="testimonial-wrapper gradient-color" id="testimonial">
          <Container>
            <div className="main-title-wrapper">
              <Subtitle Class="site-subtitle gradient-color" Name="Your Quote" />
              <Titlespan2
                Class="sitemain-subtitle"
                Name={`$${Math.round(pCR.total)}`}
              />
              <Description
                Class="site-dec"
                Name="The Shown Price is only an estimate and may increase or decrease based on demand and extent of work"
              />
              {pCR.activeAddOns.map((service, index) => (
                <Badge color="info" pill>
                  {service.title}
                </Badge>
              ))}
            </div>
          </Container>
        </section>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Are you looking for `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle event instead? To be fair, if it is just a simple calculation, why would you put it in the state? Also note, that the console.log afterwards is useless, as `setState` isn't synchronous by nature

Comment: Im using useEffect would component did update be better?

Comment: where do you use useEffect? hooks are the part of functional approach but I can see a lot of 'this' within your code that makes me thinking it is a class component

Comment: It seems like he's mixing functional and class components. Also, I'm unsure why there is this.state with data but he's using pCR object for useEffect.

Comment: The two effects are in two different files one functional and one class

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `componentDidUpdate` life cycle function in your component class. As per the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

Means, whenever the state of the component will change, the `componentDidUpdate` code block will be called. So we can place an if condition in the block to compare the new state with the previous state, can calculate total and recommit it to the state. Code

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  
  constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {
          hours: 0,
          total: 0,
          ratePerHour: 10
      };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if (prevState.hours !== this.state.hours) {
         // Calculate total
         this.setState({
             total: this.state.total + this.state.hours * this.state.ratePerHour * Math.PI
         }
      }
  }

  render() {
    return <AnotherComponent />;
  }
}
```

Plus it is important to note that (ref: [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate))

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop.

In case of any other query, please feel free to reach out in the comments.

Comment: Hey thanks, im using a functional component any way to do this with useEffect?

Comment: No it is actually a choice. The React community is slowly moving toward function based components but I kinda love class based components because of the component lifecycle features. Let me get back in a sec about doing it with `useEffect`

Comment: Checkout the code at https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-rubin-bmnl9?file=/src/index.js I have illustrated that how you can achieve it with useEffect.

Comment: I thought you are using class components as there were `this` keyword in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a minute since I've worked with newer React features but when I can I use `useEffect` in my functional components. The second parameter is the the variable you want to watch for changes. If you don't supply a second parameter it'll run similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate. An example of possible use:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [test, setTest] = useState('');

  // Specify to watch count because we have more than one state variable
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's some of their documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: I updated my question its still running when hours haven't changed.

Comment: Where does pCR.hours come from? I see `this.state.hours` but not pCR.hours.

Comment: Also, if you are using a functional component you won't have access to `this` and if you're using a class component you won't have access to `useEffect`. It seems like you're mixing the two.

Comment: @TyriqueDaniel Can you just share your whole component? That doesn't look like valid code and if it is there is enough missing that it's impossible to know what's wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63181137/use-effect-is-updating-even-when-value-doesnt-change?noredirect=1#comment111725343_63181137

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even when I added the second argument to `useEffect` which is an array of dependencies. It is running every time the component mounts instead of only if the value changes and I guess this is because I initialized my state variable like so

```
const[myStateVariable, setMyStateVariable] = React.useState('');
```

so I had to make this condition in my `useEffect` function

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if(myStateVariable !==''){
      getMyData()
    }
  }, [myStateVariable]);
```