# Use Effect is updating even when value doesnt change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Function is running even when pCR.hours hasnt changed, looknig for componnet did update functionality

```
 export const FinalQuote = () => {
      const pCR = useContext(ProductContext);
        const prevCountRef = useRef();
    
    
        useEffect(() => {
          alert('Run')
          console.log(pCR.hours, 'Final Quote Run', pCR.total);
          pCR.setTotal();
          console.error(pCR.hours);
      }, [pCR.hours]);
    
      return (
        <section classNam
```

Comment: Would it work as needed if you destructure `pCR` into `hours` and `setTotal()` (like that: `const {hours, setTotal} = useContect(ProductContext)` and use those separately (i.e. `useEffect(() => {..setTotal() ..}, [hours])`?

Comment: Is `hours` a primitive or a reference, if its a reference are you accidentally recreating the object when providing it to the context provider causing React to treat it as a different value?

Comment: Im not sure im referencing state of a context.js ?

Comment: this may be the case